# Outlook VSTO AddIn / Custom Ribbon: How to add custom Ribbon to home group (Main Window) in Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook-addin, ribbon

I tried to add the following custom ribbon  (Designer Approach) to the TabHomeGroup in Outlook (Explorer). Unfortunateyl it won't show up. Why?

I used these OfficeIds: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

```
namespace OutlookAddIn4
{

partial class Ribbon_Explorer : Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    public Ribbon_Explorer()
        : base(Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory())
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">"true", wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen, andernfalls "false".</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Vom Komponenten-Designer generierter Code

    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
    /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tab1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonTab();
        this.group1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
        this.btnSettings = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.tab1.SuspendLayout();
        this.group1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tab1
        // 
        this.tab1.ControlId.ControlIdType = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlIdType.Office;
        this.tab1.ControlId.OfficeId = "TabHomeGroup";
        this.tab1.Groups.Add(this.group1);
        this.tab1.Label = "TabHomeGroup";
        this.tab1.Name = "tab1";
        // 
        // group1
        // 
        this.group1.Items.Add(this.btnSettings);
        this.group1.Label = "group1";
        this.group1.Name = "group1";
        // 
        // btnSettings
        // 
        this.btnSettings.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.btnSettings.Image = global::OutlookAddIn4.Properties.Resources.do_48x48;
        this.btnSettings.Label = "Settings";
        this.btnSettings.Name = "btnSettings";
        this.btnSettings.ShowImage = true;
        this.btnSettings.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.btnSettings_Click);
        // 
        // Ribbon_Explorer
        // 
        this.Name = "Ribbon_Explorer";
        this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer";
        this.Tabs.Add(this.tab1);
        this.Load += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventHandler(this.Ribbon_Explorer_Load);
        this.tab1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tab1.PerformLayout();
        this.group1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.group1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab tab1;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup group1;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton btnSettings;
    internal SettingsForm settingsForm;
}

partial class ThisRibbonCollection
{
    internal Ribbon_Explorer Ribbon_Explorer
    {
        get { return this.GetRibbon<Ribbon_Explorer>(); }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `TabHomeGroup` is visible at the moment your add-in is started?

Anyway, you need to use the `TabHome` idMso instead if you want to place your custom UI on the `Home` tab in the Explorer window.

Comment: I thought that TabHome would be always visible. Furthermore I think Outlook always starts with TabMail. I use the Designer not the XML approach. So from what I understand this approach is only possible with XML approach, right?

Comment: You can use the designer as well, just specify the `TabHome` instead of `TabHomeGroup`.